# Как в Django связать одно поле с другим полем внешней таблицы?

Tags: django, django-orm

Необходимо связать 2 поля одной таблицы с такими же 2 полями внешней таблицы, как это сделать в Django?

Вот чтобы легче было понять вопрос, сделал такой пример

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

В Django я только вижу связь с самой таблицей , но не индивидуально нужным полем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Общие данные использовать отдельным классом

Comment: И вроде вы тут не первый день, но почему то до сих пор вставляет код каритнкой. Добавьте ваш код текстовым блоком, а картинку удалите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поясню комментарий.

Создать класс

```py
class Match(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    opponent = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
```

И использовать эту сущность для обеих команд, собирая данные через связанные таблицы.

Comment: Dmitry, да я понял Вашу мысль, это действительно хорошее решение, но возможно ли сделать чтобы исходные данные остались как в примере и соответствующая нужная мне связь с полями? Без изменения структур таблиц

Comment: @РусланКамов так вы и не изменяете структуру существующих таблиц. Вы расширяете только. Поле конечно можно достать и с помощью query, только это будет лишняя логика. Напишите в вопросе как выглядят ваши классы для релевантные таблиц

Comment: спасибо, да пока никак, пока просто в ворде таблицу создал и прикидываю, как объяединять их. Это мой первый опыт когда я самостоятельные пет проект по базам данным делаю. А строчка кода, чисто для того была написана, чтобы показать какую я вижу логику в этой связи Один ко многим.

Comment: @РусланКамов рисуйте базу данных со всеми отношениями.  Создайте архитектуру, и на базе неё пишите модели

Comment: А где Вы обычно рисуете? Я самый самый первый раз пытаюсь это сделать сам

Comment: Drawio, но это не специализированная программа под это дело

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, жаль на проверку показать Вам нельзя что получится((

Comment: @РусланКамов нет необходимости, потом сами поймёте свои ошибки. Это путь)

Comment: @РусланКамов я рисую на бумаге / в блокноте. Мне этого более чем достаточно.